# Hiding media uploaded by other users in wordpress multisite?

Tags: multisite, uploads, user-access

I am using WordPress Multisite and want to hide media which others have uploaded. Like if X User of that site has uploaded any media in the site, Y User should not be able to see or access this from their login.

Comment: Have a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Allow access to own content only
 */
function my_authored_content($query) {

//get current user info to see if they are allowed to access ANY posts and pages
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
// set current user to $is_user
$is_user = $current_user->user_login;

//if is admin or 'is_user' does not equal #username
if (!current_user_can('manage_options')){
    //if in the admin panel
    if($query->is_admin) {

        global $user_ID;
        $query->set('author',  $user_ID);

    }
    return $query;
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'my_authored_content');
```

> This will only let admin and the author see the content.
>
> You can either add it to the main functions file or turn it into a
>   plugin.